# How to return two different Observable from resolve function and subscribe it into component

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to return two Observable of different types from on resolve function in route.ts and want to subscribe that Observable in Component.ts but its shows undefined response.
I also tried this link [Angular 4 How to return multiple observables in resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146996/angular-4-how-to-return-multiple-observables-in-resolver)

route.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class View360Resolve implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private service: View360Service) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        const id = route.params['id'] ? route.params['id'] : null;
        if (id) {
            var view360: View360;
            var view360_2: View360_2;

            var respp = this.service.findView360_2(1).pipe(
                filter((response: HttpResponse<View360_2>) => response.ok),
                map((View360_2: HttpResponse<View360_2>) => View360_2.body)
            );

            var resp = this.service.find(id).pipe(
                filter((response: HttpResponse<View360>) => response.ok),
                map((view360: HttpResponse<View360>) => view360.body)
            );

            return forkJoin([
                respp,
                resp]);

            }
        return forkJoin([
            of(new View360_2()),
            of(new View360())]);
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to get the data from activatedRoute in component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {

        this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ result }) => {

            this.view360_2 = result[0];
            this.view360 = result[1];
            console.log("view360_2===" + this.view360_2);
            console.log("view360===" + this.view360);

        });
    }
```

Both the objects this.view360_2, this.view360 are showing undefined data. kindly help to resolve this, Thanks.

Comment: Add code samples else no one will be ready to work from the scratch.

The quick thing you could refer, you could use `Observable<any>` which could be used for all kind types.

Comment: You could return an array of observables. Would it help?

Comment: @jithil I had by mistake submitted the incomplete question, now I have completed it.

Comment: @jpavel can you please refer the above code which i have edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

In your resolver:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    return forkJoin(respp, resp);
}
```

This should work with this:

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I put together a working example built upon a test I was doing using MatTabGroup + Angular animations: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resolver-sample?file=app%2Ftab-nav-bar-basic-example.ts